# Mousemove event - div position based on mouse position is inverting

Tags: javascript

Edit -  here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cLahpqoj/1/ and here is an example of what i'm trying to do: https://www.seventh.tv/

---

perhaps my math on setting door position is bad and screwing things up. noticed the mouse postion and door position are changing places in values. logging:

```
{doorX: -1066, x: 396, doorY: -1367, y: 164}
{doorX: 396, x: -1065, doorY: 164, y: -1367}
```

from:

```
   let mouseX =  e.offsetX;
        let mouseY = e.offsetY;

        let doorX = currentDoorRect.x;
        let doorY = currentDoorRect.y;

        let x = doorX;
        let y = doorY;

        x =  -( x + (mouseX) );
        y =  -( y + (mouseY) );

        let transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';
        currentDoor.style.transform = transform;




          console.log( {
            doorX,
            x,
            doorY,
            y
          });
```

---

I'm trying to move a div with the `transform:translate(x,y)` css property based on the current div position and the mouse position.

I'm logging the x and y values passed to the transform change and noticing for every value change, there is one proceeding one with something like `x: -1, y:0` and then immediately back to what the value should be (i.e `x:-563, y:424`)

I'm using Vue.js and the function is :

```
<template>
  <div ref="test-container" id="test-container" class="h-full relative" 
  @mousedown.prevent="disableMiddleClickScroll"
  @mousemove="moveDoors"
  @wheel="disableWheelScroll">
    <div
      :ref="`door-${index}`"
      v-for="index in numDoors" :key="index"
      class="door bg-gray-300 p-8  text-center rounded flex-none">
      Door
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

...

moveDoors(e) {
        let mouseX =  e.offsetX;
        let mouseY = e.offsetY;

   
          let currentDoor = this.$refs[`door-1`];
          let currentDoorRect = currentDoor.getBoundingClientRect();

          let doorX = currentDoorRect.x;
          let doorY = currentDoorRect.y;

          let x =  -( doorX + (mouseX) );
          let y =  -( doorY + (mouseY) );

          console.log( {
            x,
            y
          });

          let transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';
          currentDoor.style.transform = transform;

    
        
      },
```

the event is called like this:

example of console log:

```
{x: 1, y: -0}
{x: -547, y: -426}
{x: 1, y: -0}
{x: -545, y: -426}
{x: -0, y: 1}
{x: -544, y: -425}
{x: -0, y: 1}
{x: -546, y: -424}
{x: -1, y: -0}
```

The container css is:

```
#test-container {
  position: fixed;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    
}
```

Please let me know if there's not enough information to debug. I think this is all that is relevant.

Comment: I will change my example since I set to only 1 door in the loop. even with no loop, same issue. the door div flashes and the x and y values show odd 0 and -1 values. the mousemove event is also on the container, not the doors.

Comment: can you make your example verifiable, i.e a working snippet

Comment: Yes, i'll do that. I used Vue CLI to generate this, so I'll see what I can do inside jsfiddle

Comment: @LawrenceCherone sorry for the delay. here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cLahpqoj/1/

Comment: I'm not sure if it is actually firing twice. but still confused about why the position flips to -0 and 1 randomly which makes my div flash and move elsewhere

Comment: it doesn't fire twice though it looks like it is, it's flipping back between the two values because the door is moving and you're taking the door position + mouse position into account in the calculation, every odd position when its outside the door it inverts

Comment: you're right - it is inverting. not firing twice. but i'm not sure how to solve this. i need it to move relative to the last position the door is in. can you suggest anything?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen? The `getBoundingClientRect` values are relative to the viewport and do take into account the transformation you applied to it. So if in the first call you translate the element by 10px, in the next call gBCR will tell you the element is 10px further than what it was on the previous call. Not knowing what you were expecting, it's impossible for us to help you more...

Comment: @Kaiido As I said in my question, I want to move the div relative to the position of the mouse. if this is not possible the way i'm doing, feel free to suggest something. i don't think it's "impossible" to help me here.

Comment: what does "relative" means here? It **is** currently moving relatively to the mouse position. It could go the inverse direction, the same direction by a factor of 3000, really anything, all those would be "relative to the position of the mouse", but you can guess how they are all completely different.

Comment: clearly I do not wish it to snap back to x:0 and y:0 or similar. I want it to move on the x and y on the inverse mouse movement. i found an example: https://www.seventh.tv/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is what this website is doing, then yes, your math is not the ones you need, and your strategy is also a bit off.
What they do there is a simple mapping from the viewport position to the content's one. You don't need to move each element on their own, but only the main container.

Basically, if you move your cursor to the center of the viewport, the content will move so that its center is at the center of the viewport. If you move it to the top left corner of the screen, then the content will move so that you see the top left corner of the content.

To do this, there are multiple strategies. One is to map the mouse position to a [0, 1] range, and then multiply this ratio by the content's size. You then just have to adjust for half the viewport size for the whole to be correctly centered.

```js
const content = document.querySelector(".content");

document.onmousemove = (evt) => {
  // the mouse position (in the viewport)
  const viewport_x = evt.clientX;
  const viewport_y = evt.clientY;
  // the viewport size
  const viewport_width  = window.innerWidth;
  const viewport_height = window.innerHeight;
  // the mouse position, still relative to the viewport
  // but in a range [0, 1]
  const ratio_x = viewport_x / viewport_width;
  const ratio_y = viewport_y / viewport_height;
  
  // our content's size
  const content_rect = content.getBoundingClientRect();
  const content_width = content_rect.width;
  const content_height = content_rect.height;
  // transform the mouse position to the content's position
  const content_x = content_width * ratio_x;
  const content_y = content_height * ratio_y;
  // remove it from half the size of the viewport
  // so that aiming at the center of the viewport
  // shows the center of our content
  const translate_x = viewport_width  / 2 - content_x;
  const translate_y = viewport_height / 2 - content_y;

  content.style.setProperty("--translate-x", translate_x + "px");
  content.style.setProperty("--translate-y", translate_y + "px");

};
```

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  transition: transform .5s ease-out;
  width: 150vw;
  height: 250vh;
  transform: translate(var(--translate-x), var(--translate-y));
  --translate-x: -25vw; /* (150vw - 100vw) / 2 */
  --translate-y: -75vh; /* (250vh - 100vw) / 2 */
}
.frame {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  counter-increment: frame;
}
.frame::after {
  content: counter(frame);
}
body, :root {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="frame"></div>  
  <div class="frame"></div>
  <div class="frame"></div>

  <div class="frame"></div>
  <div class="frame"></div>
  <div class="frame"></div>

  <div class="frame"></div>
  <div class="frame"></div>
  <div class="frame"></div>

  <div class="frame"></div>
  <div class="frame"></div>
  <div class="frame"></div>

  <div class="frame"></div>
  <div class="frame"></div>
  <div class="frame"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Kaiido. I will look into this today. When I inspected their site, I saw a transform on each element changing - not the container. So that's why I attempted what I did.

Comment: Well to be honest I didn't even look at "how" they do it, as I said there are various strategies, but to me moving only the container sounds like the easiest way.

Comment: Thank you. This seems like a much better way to approach. and way easier. I think the site I referenced was using a tool anyway (whatever https://webflow.com/ is). I think this is great - I just need to not allow so much empty space on x,y coords when the container is at bounds. shouldn't be an issue. thanks again

Comment: @Kaiido Hello, with this solution how would the movement be limited to the limit of the content? That is, there are no blank spaces

Comment: @good_afternoon Hello, how did you remove the white spaces on the sides?